# Partially Automated Migration of Monolith to MicroService

Tags: microservices, automation, migration

I am struggling to find some methods / concepts or even implementations of partially automated processes to split a monolith into microservices. Of cause I do not expect any solution that will make poof and the migration is done but any kind of concept or software that assists in the process would be nice.

I searched for hours now and can not seem to find anything. It is very surprising to me that I can not find even one tool that analyses the way a monolith accesses the data base and suggests something about how cutting of certain areas may help in migrating the system. I can imagine there maybe are some other points that could be automated in some way.
Of cause such a software would not understand the context of what meaning the accessed information have but software that manages some kind of context should be (at least internally) somehow divided into contextual and/or functional services etc. that correspond to specific parts of information.

**So finally my question is:**

Does anyone know any kind of concept or software that does this and I just did not find it?
If not, are there any reasons why such a concept or software is impossible to code?

Thank you very much
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found this paper that contains some discussion about that topic and also lists some Approches with Stategies and Tools, when they exist.

From Monolith to Microservices: A Classification of Refactoring Approaches
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.10059.pdf

Comment: You should rather consider the Sam Newman's book `Monolith to microservices patterns`

Answer (score 3):

> It is very surprising to me that I can not find even one tool that analyses the way a monolith accesses the data base and suggests something about how cutting of certain areas may help in migrating the system.

The tricky and most important part to migrate a monolith to a microservices architecture is the domain model decomposition.

So we need to have a deep knowledge of the business domain, rules and invariants.

No tools can have this knowledge. Your tool is your `brain`.

Then you have to mix your domain knowledge with some DDD modeling concepts like `bounded context`, `aggregate`, `event map` ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will read more about all that and maybe even try to build something myself. Even if I will fail I at least learned first hand why it doesn't work =)